# I have an object like this ! I need to remove ''_demo" ! I tried this way it does not work ! does anyone know any suggestions?

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here][1]
I have an object like this and I have to remove '_demo' in each item I tired below it did not work!

here is the image!   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krIGK.png

```
datalist.forEach((data)=>{
    for(let da in data){
        da.replace('_demo','')
    }
})
```

Comment: Please post the data as JSON text, not a link to a painting of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Object.keys` to map each key and replace the `_demo` part.

```js
let datalist = [
  {
    "Index": "312",
    "test No_demo": "skjhksdjhfsh",
    "Date created": "26/06/2018",
    "Updateddate_demo": "26/06/2018",
    "Address_demo": "testing"
  },
  {
    "Index": "312",
    "test No_demo": "skjhksdjhfsh",
    "Date created": "26/06/2018",
    "Updateddate_demo": "26/06/2018",
    "Address_demo": "testing"
  }
]

let res = datalist.map(row => {
  let x = {}
  Object.keys(row).map( k => {
    x[k.replace('_demo', '')] = row[k]
  });
  return x
});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: first map iterates datalist's objects and second map iterates object's keys, I don't know how to do it with one loop only

Comment: How to make it work with an array of objects? https://jsfiddle.net/9u8x1w4v/

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the name of an existing key, Either you delete the old key and create a new key with its value, or create a new object with the new key instead of the old key.

```
datalist = datalist.map(({ "test No_demo": test, ...data })=>{
    return {
       ...data,
       "test No": test
    }
})
```

Comment: datalist.forEach((data)=>{
    for(let da in data){
        // da.replace('_demo','')
        if (da.indexOf('_demo') > -1) {
            var str = da;
            var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf('_demo');
  
            str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
            console.log(str);
        }}
}). i tried this it worked in console but it did not save into the object!

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't directly alter an object's key: if the object key [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) "_demo" create a new key, assign the value of the old object property to the new property defined by the new key, and then delete the old property.

```js
const obj = {
  a_demo: 1,
  b: 2,
  c_demo: 3
};

for (const key in obj) {
  if (key.includes('_demo')) {
    const newKey = key.replace('_demo', '');
    obj[newKey] = obj[key];
    delete obj[key];
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

If you didn't want to mutate the original object:

```js
const obj = {
  a_demo: 1,
  b: 2,
  c_demo: 3
};

const out = {};

for (const key in obj) {
  const newKey = key.replace('_demo', '');
  out[newKey] = obj[key];
}

console.log(out);
```